# Error in the reportar command. Object has no attribute send on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
async def reportar(ctx, *, text=None):
  owner = bot.get_user(773913180271280129)
  x = discord.Embed(title='**Report Error!**')
  x.add_field(name='Server:', value=ctx.guild.name, inline=False)
  x.add_field(name='ID of the Server:', value=ctx.guild.id, inline=False)
  x.add_field(name='Report:', value=text, inline=False)
  x.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
  x.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
  x.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  await owner.send(embed=x)
  #Developer
  await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
  #reaction
  y = discord.Embed(title='#Team B0T')
  y.add_field(name=f'**Hello {ctx.author.display_name}**', value='*YOUR MESSAGE*')
  y.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
  await ctx.author.send(embed=y)
```

I am trying to make a reportar command. If any user face problem in my bot. It can report and a Dm would be sent to me by the bot.
But, i am getting an error. Please help me out

Error -

````
Ignoring exception in command reportar:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\OneDrive\Desktop\Coding and editing\Mezuhashi.py", line 50, in reportar
    await owner.send(embed=x)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'```
````

Comment: The line `owner = bot.get_user(773913180271280129)` assigns `owner` the value `None`, and you cannot call `send` function on `None`, which is was the error states

Comment: so please give the correct code

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the User Intent. To do that, add these 2 lines of code to your main file under the imports:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True  # Subscribe to the privileged members intent.

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix", intents=intents)
```

Comment: You also need to pass the intents into the bot constructor.

Comment: Yes, you can do that by adding intents=intents into `Bot()`

Comment: You might wanna add that to your answer, otherwise it won’t work.